# Apple Pay In App Provisioning : LinkAndProvisionResponse API

Tags: ios, objective-c, applepay, wallet, mastercard

In the implementation document of Apple Pay In-app Provisioning, it refers to the

> ***LinkAndProvisionResponse***

API. Please share your inputs for this API; and where and how exactly it need to be invoked.

Comment: did you find anything about this?